# can't access env and config function in laravel on production

Tags: php, laravel, vps

i finish my laravel project and push it to my VPS.

so at some point am sending email message to admin. but laravel is giving me null for env

```
 Mail::to(env("ADMIN_EMAIL"))->send(new NewOrderAdmin());
```

i tried to set the ADMIN_EMAIL in config app.php and call it from there

```
config(app.ADMIN_EMAIL)
```

but still giving me null. and this is only on production for some reason

I have checked my .env and tried to clear cache but still no result

Comment: run `php artisan config:clear` then check

Comment: do not call `env` outside of the config files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to clear your config cache so

run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: they are on production so they should just recache it  `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @lagbox what is cmd for `recache ` .?